# Parallelization of outer product on multiple vectors using cython

Tags: numpy, parallel-processing, cython

Suppose to have a numpy array m of shape (N, M) and I want to compute

```
res = np.zeros((M, M))
for i in range(N):
   res += np.outer(m[i], m[i])
```

This loop can be made more efficient using `einsum`, i.e.

```
res = np.sum(np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', m , m, axis=0)
```

but this requires the storage of a N x M x M matrix, which can be (*and in my case is*) very demanding.

I thought to build this function in cython, using parallelzation

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from cython.parallel import prange

def get_s(double[:,:] m):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i = 0
    cdef int n = m.shape[1]
    
    res = 0.
    for i in prange(n, nogil=True):
       res += np.outer(m[i], m[i])
    return res
```

The idea of this code is that
The run of this code produces a lot of errors since I am using python objects, disallowed operations, and I don't know how to properly initialize `res`.

Comment: This question could use some editing: none of the code snippets is complete or working, sentences missing parts. If you have multiple issues ask multiple questions (after searching online and having documented your search).

Comment: Your einsum usage doesn't make much sense. `np.einsum('ij,ik->jk', A , A, optimize='optimal')` is enough. This is actually only a dot product, which is detected by einsum if optimization is turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use numpy functions (`np.outer`) is the nogil context. So you just spell it out with loops.
Futhermore, your `res` variable seems to be an array, so you'll need to declare one and initialize it.
Last, you want the loops to compile to C, thus use typed memoryviews. It's easiest to use numpy arrays for memory management and take memoryviews of them. Taking it all together,

```
%%cython -a

cimport cython

import numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def m_outer(double[:, ::1] a):
    n, m = a.shape[0], a.shape[1]
    cdef double[:, ::1] resm = np.zeros((m, m))

    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            for k in range(a.shape[1]):
                resm[j, k] += a[i, j] * a[i, k]
    return np.asarray(resm)
```

A way to write these things (maybe *the* way) is to write it in python (nevermind the speed), validate the output on a small example (I use 3-by-4), then cythonize.

When cythonizing, use `%cython -a` and examine the generated C code.

Now, there are two obvious opportunities here: reorder the loops to lift loop-constants and use prange. Both are left as an exercise to the reader.

And the very last note. Unless it's an educational exercise, note that what you are really computing is a matrix product `A.T @ A`.

Answer (score 1):

Your iteration:

```
In [139]: res = np.zeros((4,4))                                                                      
In [140]: for i in range(3): res += np.outer(m[i],m[i])                                              
In [141]: res                                                                                        
Out[141]: 
array([[ 80.,  92., 104., 116.],
       [ 92., 107., 122., 137.],
       [104., 122., 140., 158.],
       [116., 137., 158., 179.]])
```

We can do the same `outer` with broadcasting:

```
In [142]: np.sum(m[:,:,None]*m[:,None,:], axis=0)                                                    
Out[142]: 
array([[ 80,  92, 104, 116],
       [ 92, 107, 122, 137],
       [104, 122, 140, 158],
       [116, 137, 158, 179]])
```

(yes, this does make a temporary (N,M,M) array)

The suggested single step einsum:

```
In [143]: np.einsum('ij,ik->jk',m,m)                                                                 
Out[143]: 
array([[ 80,  92, 104, 116],
       [ 92, 107, 122, 137],
       [104, 122, 140, 158],
       [116, 137, 158, 179]])
```

Which is just a simple dot product (with the appropriate transpose):

```
In [144]: m.T.dot(m)                                                                                 
Out[144]: 
array([[ 80,  92, 104, 116],
       [ 92, 107, 122, 137],
       [104, 122, 140, 158],
       [116, 137, 158, 179]])
In [145]: m.T@m                                                                                      
Out[145]: 
array([[ 80,  92, 104, 116],
       [ 92, 107, 122, 137],
       [104, 122, 140, 158],
       [116, 137, 158, 179]])
```

Since `numpy` dot's use fast BLAS code, I doubt if you can improve on it with `cython`.

Comment: I guess this is the best way to do it. I feel very dumb to didn't see it on my own! Thanks :).